# Maximally symmetric hyperbolic 3-manifolds with finite volume

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, symmetric-spaces

In physics, standard cosmology is build with simple maximally symmetric 3-manifolds (spacelike time-slices of constant curvature, e.g. $S^3$ or less popular the hyperbolic space $H^3$). Since $S^3$ has a finite volume it seems natural to ask whether there also exists a maximally symmetric hyperbolic counterpart which also has a finite volume? (An answer in layman's terms would be fine, if possible.)

Comment: You probably want to read about Thurston geometries. Also about the notion of "locally symmetric space". That $H^3$ is "less popular"? well, hyperbolic 3-dimensional geometry has been a major theme in geometric topology in the last 40 years!

Comment: Sorry, but less popular in standard cosmology, because it is generally believed that space-time in general relativity is not negatively curved.

Comment: In any case: finite volume manifolds with curvature $-1$ usually have a very small amount of symmetries, whence the notion of locally symmetric space.

Comment: In GR we sometimes say "locally maximally symmetric" to mean: for every point on the manifold there exists an open neighbourhood of said point which is isometrically diffeomorphic to an open set on a "maximally symmetric" space. So for the purposes of this question said maximally symmetric space would be $H^3$. There should be lots of examples* which are not $H^3$ itself, but whether any have finite volume, I do not know. (*In the Lorentzian case the BTZ black hole geometry is some quotient of maximally symmetric $AdS_3$ but I do not remember the details now.)

Comment: Equivalently, such locally maximally symmetric spaces admit the maximum number of Killing vector fields on some neighbourhood of every point.

Comment: @AlexArvanitakis: there are many such examples with finite volume.  Hyperbolic manifolds are a huge topic of research in low-dimensional topology. The simplest 3-dimensional example with finite volume is perhaps the complement of the figure-eight knot in the 3-sphere (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure-eight_knot_(mathematics)). The simplest compact example is perhaps Seifert--Weber dodecahedral space (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Weber_space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kojima](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271523/1-s2.0-S0166864100X02064/1-s2.0-0166864188900272/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIESPHm0uX8EZMiqb6338fUic%2BRqVJVS9xhy9KnZHrUV9AiAPNfg6RNp6n%2FEZwlr0noHWvQPjoKhiQWuXso9vK6YKYyq0AwgcEAMaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMI0EymxuxNmDRS4q%2FKpEDAda1RhKT69S2RAk20XdzgYw8ifArH4bIeXDzJG3u1I%2BtjL9nnTw4MMq4oyChyd4ddXxEvwidJ2eKY%2Ft7GAFSr2w%2F537W7eoGwAs4fWTgGMnLCKGTRklUKs%2FDAhtu0jAC1YvvNOAUDB82O3%2F%2BeiQbAmjTY4t6%2FX%2BLEmprdH0%2Fp29BeYuMZreYyFIgVhSeYK6gjcGFUX2oPKm5swVP%2BbiAxzVlsNrcINZ5gkbCWv8zS5adq56sIMt1DviVsjPxOgM2g7VCiuW5Y4NfVIdDHGaYioOqlOU9TMDre1m71dRUSGk1Yi6vLLgJAmUazUJ8k%2BdDHki2caPGI87vy8vagzvpQtwIbWEDt5QO8HosI4lphEU9OL37OFJTrwQ8TbJP%2Fa4P3ebs7XGgzKZ6K1JYy06Ob870Sbbiz3qnSCEYYBd%2BpSpQakXnxeQBBMj1DrzlpqWt5olIkfhxAzRGaxBRQHIaCufo20xD9RmT9ucCWdkDvpEI2ayRoSxonjvHda%2FoKh3pZS6vf0EwH2h0xLH1qB5MHzcwjeuV9gU67AE9OvT52DHeoSWUr5HXqRC2euQLbhZXNzUoe1lM1vZ5G6Dma%2FAoJ7RXoAhJ4hvydHRLCLkPpRbecjMn%2BBK7Ignqu3Hs4XdmrRP9FpyMykAKTSldKFilO7Oav6sKD6nnLUAr8l2nwMXRLCfhqrCYXMZd3CVQcfCku2SuIauYfZiFAUYPXTrHpfo%2B%2BJyIDXop0iP9KedM%2FT6mhGdmezaqC5r0N8b%2BbZdEtg3GaqSSD5X1EGsfV9Xyrzqk%2BkAzxNyvwLZX3%2BisWttjG3b22oG6jBYRwnvuSfRijr4NyUwTfcLetK9kKC2Yr7SFibY7zw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200520T192755Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYXAXMMQH5%2F20200520%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7d952939cba402f5e08320870279926b382f2d1da266cb31aa7c48acf2cd2ad3&hash=1c759f3b7d9f16f06a4a09132142327b432c1978dbfcaf909aa35728e59057da&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0166864188900272&tid=spdf-23fd3eb1-e6b0-4957-bd52-277671e79257&sid=914d307d6c4cc14a9768b150209568da6d0agxrqb&type=client) has proved that every finite group occurs as the symmetry group of some compact hyperbolic 3-manifold. Hence there is nothing like a hyperbolic 3-manifold of maximal symmetry.

The same result is true in higher dimensions by [Belolipetsky-Lubotzky](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406607.pdf).

Comment: Sorry, but I need some help to understand your answer. As far as I know there is a hyperbolic 3-manifold which satisfies homogenity and isotropy (space of constant sectional curvature -1), but it has an infinite volume. Do I understand right that there is no such manifold with finite volume?

Comment: Yes, there is no such manifold. A finite-volume complete hyperbolic manifold has only finitely many symmetries.

Comment: @Bruno Martelli thank you for the annotation.